# Можно ли использовать lead/lag в postgresql с where ? Есть ли обходные пути?

Tags: sql, postgresql, функции, оконные-функции

у меня есть таблица с некоторыми событиями

```
    event time   id user_id
    a     11:00  1   1
    a     12:00  2   1
    b     13:00  3   1
    a     13:30  4   2
    b     14:00  5   2
    b     14:10  6   2
```

Я хочу взять для каждого user_id для события b то событие а, следом за которым оно(событие b) идет,
например, для `b(id=5) и для b(id=6) это a(id=4), для b(id=3) это a(id=2)`.
Кажется, эту проблему бы решало использование `lag(id) over (partition by user_id order by time) с where event='a'`, но я нигде не увидела возможности использования where clause с lead/lag. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли способ решить мою задачу ?

Upd скрипт:

```
drop table if exists t1;

create table t1
(
  event char
  ,time timestamp
  ,id integer
  ,user_id integer
);
insert into
  t1
values('a', '2021-08-09 11:00', 1, 1),('a', '2021-08-09 12:00', 2, 1),('b', '2021-08-09 13:00', 3, 1),('a', '2021-08-09 13:30',
    4, 2),('b', '2021-08-09 14:00', 5, 2),('b', '2021-08-09 14:10', 6, 2);
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
event     time   id user_id lag_id
    a     11:00  1   1    any value
    a     12:00  2   1    any value
    b     13:00  3   1    2
    a     13:30  4   2    any value
    b     14:00  5   2    4
    b     14:10  6   2    4
```

Comment: Оконные функции применяются к набору записей, полученному после группировки и пост-отбора (HAVING). Соответственно во WHERE оконные функции неприменимы. Используйте CTE либо подзапрос с оконной функцией и отбор во внешнем запросе.

Comment: @Akina а вы можете, пожалуйста, если не сложно, на этом примере показать, как это можно сделать ?

Comment: Замените таблицу на CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO скрипты, и покажите в виде таблицы полный требуемый результат для этих данных.

Comment: С другой стороны, если (id1>id2 => time1>time2), то куда как разумнее подзапрос по второй копии таблицы, или даже лимитированный LATERAL подзапрос.

Comment: Делаете запрос с тем lead/lag который вам нужен. Оборачиваете свой полученный запрос в еще один `select * from (ваш запрос) x where c ...`

Comment: @Mike разве я тогда не получу например для события b с id=6 как предыдущее событие событие b с id=5, вместо a с id=4 и не выкину его просто следующим where ?

Comment: @Akina добавила скрипт и ожидаемый результат :)

Comment: @user446149 Да, получите. Ну я на вопрос как в where оконную функцию использовать написал. не вчитывался в подробности. Если вчитаться, то Akina прав, тут оконные функции не помогут (ну без сильных извращений, когда именно события A будут каким нибудь last_value() спускаться вниз и потом анализироваться, уровня 3-4 вложенных запросов выйдет), лучше подзапросом к той же таблице, собственно как в его ответе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.*,
       ( SELECT id
         FROM test t2
         WHERE t2.event = 'a'
           AND t2.time < t1.time
           AND t1.event = 'b'
         ORDER BY t2.time DESC LIMIT 1) lag_id
FROM test t1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b64ac6c6abd7e4cca344ffa0cf9aaa18

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а как мы учитываем user_id здесь ? 
>для каждого user_id для события b то событие а, следом за которым оно(событие b) идет <

Прошу прощения, что сразу не придумала кейс на этот случай :(

Comment: но and t1.user_id=t2.user_id полагаю эта строчка поможет)

Comment: @user446149 Вы правы.